# Getting Error While Using Reflection to get Field Data

Tags: java, spring-mvc, reflection, field

I am trying to fetch Field name as well as field value using Reflection.

I am passing dynamic classes as per operation needed.

I have made a method to fetch field name and value, i am getting field name but not getting field value.
when I am using following code it gives me an error `java.lang.IllegalAccessException` stating that can not access private member of class.

Following is my `UPDATED` code :

```
public String SerializeCommand(ICommand command){

    StringBuilder command_text = new StringBuilder();
    Field [] f = command.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for(Field field : f){
        field.setAccessible(true);
        command_text.append(field.getName() + ",");
        try {
            System.out.println(field.get(command.getClass()));
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return command_text.toString();
}
```

Here ICommand is a class name for it, suppose if operation is add then add class will be passed.

Any Idea what to do to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code.

```
public String SerializeCommand(ICommand command){

    StringBuilder command_text = new StringBuilder();
    Field [] f = command.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    try{
    for(Field field : f){
        field.setAccessible(true);
        command_text.append(field.getName() + ",");
        System.out.println("Value :: " + field.get(command));
    }
    }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return command_text.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of command.getClass() pass the object of command class. The value contains by object not by class

Comment: I can't create object of that class. Here ICommand is an interface and I am implementing that in each class. I can't create of that one.

Comment: Ok, But without object how you could expect value ? Anyways you have to get the object to get the values. Instead of ICommand use the object of subclasses of ICommand.

Comment: But how to create object of it,I can't because classes are loaded at run time.So how to do that ? Any idea ? It's not sure that which class will be loaded at run time.

Comment: Can you try this System.out.println("Value :: " + field.get(command)); If field is private use field.setAccessible(true); before get the value.

Comment: It's giving me Same Error without running the application, `IllegalAccessException`

Comment: It is not any error .. It is checked exception that either catched by try catch block or throws from your method .. just add this line at your method level throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException ...  ... Just for example your method will be like public String SerializeCommand(ICommand command) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException{

Comment: when I am doing so it gives me an error where I am calling this method.

Comment: Seems you are very confused in basic fundamentals of Java ... I just posted a code as a separate answer. Try that .. I am not seeing any exception/error on my system at least .. not sure about yours.

Answer (score 0):

Java also takes care of not being able to access private members, even when doing it via reflection. But constructors, methods, and fields are [`AccessibleObject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html)s, which provides a method to flag the member as being accessible although it might be private:

```
field.setAccessible(true);
```

Afterwards you can read it and even set a new value on it.

---

An edit to make it clear. Consider the following simple record class:

```
public class Record {
    private int length;
    private String name;
    public Record(int length, String name) {
        this.length = length;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getLength() { return length; }
    public String getName() { return name; }
}
```

And now let's write a reflection test program:

```
public class ReflectionTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Record record = new Record(42, "42");
        Field[] fields = record.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            System.out.println(field.getName() + " => " + field.get(record));
        }
    }
}
```

This will result in an `IllegalAccessException`, as the private fields cannot be accessed. Now change the foreach loop a little:

```
        for (Field field : fields) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            System.out.println(field.getName() + " => " + field.get(record));
        }
```

This time you will see expected output:

> length => 42
>
> name => 42

Your mistake also was to call the get method on the class and not on the object. This would be like this little modification:

```
        for (Field field : fields) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            System.out.println(field.getName() + " => " + field.get(record.getClass()));
        }
```

This time you will see an `IllegalArgumentException` (not an `IllegalAccessException`).

Comment: Shall I have to make all field public for to access data of that class ?

Comment: What do you mean? I described a solution, how you can access fields, even if they are private.

Comment: But sir it still giving me same error of `IllegalAccessException` without running the code.

Comment: If you set the field as accessible prior to calling get() or getName() or anything else on it, it will work. So, the statement 'field.setAccessible(true);' must be the very first statement inside your foreach loop.

Comment: Yes I have write on first line in for loop but still giving me same error. see my updated code..

Comment: I now see, that you pass in the wrong object into the get() method. Pass in the command object (the method's parameter). I fear, you are not very familiar with reflection. Maybe you should redesign your software.

Comment: Yes Sir, today I am using reflection first time..  method's parameter means which one ?? Sorry if you don't mine will you give me some suggestion on it.. I need your help sir.

Comment: Sir my problem is that I am passing dynamic classes as command.suppose i will click on add then add class will pass and if delete then delete class will pass so it's not possible to create object of class loaded at run time.

Comment: It does not matter, where your object comes from. In your code, it is the method's parameter. In my example code, I created it, but only for demonstration.

Comment: I have tried using `command c = new command();` but I can't. and ICommand is an interface so i can't. the classes which are loaded at run time that all classes implement ICommand interface.

Comment: Phhhh ... How shall I try to explain? Seems, you are not understanding. Try this: field.get(command). And for now on, let's stop this dicussion. If you still don't understand, you should consider taking some books and tutorials and learn the beginnings.